# Make my web page offer download of zipfile

Tags: html, django, download, localhost

I am building an archive where people can download zip-files (the url is localhost:8000/downloads). I have the zip-files in the games folder (in relation to where manage.py resides). When I pass over with cursor the address shows "localhost:8000/downloads/.../games/GC_007 Goldeneye.zip" which gives "no download"
This is what I put in the link:

```
<a href="games/GC_007 Goldeneye.zip" download>007 Goldeneye</a>

"localhost:8000/downloads/.../games/GC_007 Goldeneye.zip"
```

is what I get which does not work.

Comment: How have you configured the `games` folder in your Python code?  You have to tell Django to serve that folder as static files.

Comment: So if I use href ="{% static 'GC_007 Goldeneye.zip' %}"?

Comment: IF you have configured `STATIC_URL = "games"`, then that should work.